# issue with slowly geting data from api to vue view

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js

I have issue with very slowly getting data from laravel api to vue view, I did tutorial where I have:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const client = axios.create({
    baseURL: '/api',
});

export default {
    all(params) {
        return client.get('users', params);
    },
    find(id) {
        return client.get(`users/${id}`);
    },
    update(id, data) {
        return client.put(`users/${id}`, data);
    },
    delete(id) {
        return client.delete(`users/${id}`);
    },
};

<script>
import api from "../api/users";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      message: null,
      loaded: false,
      saving: false,
      user: {
        id: null,
        name: "",
        email: ""
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onDelete() {
      this.saving = true;
      api.delete(this.user.id).then(response => {
        this.message = "User Deleted";
        setTimeout(() => this.$router.push({ name: "users.index" }), 1000);
      });
    },
    onSubmit(event) {
      this.saving = true;

      api
        .update(this.user.id, {
          name: this.user.name,
          email: this.user.email
        })
        .then(response => {
          this.message = "User updated";
          setTimeout(() => (this.message = null), 10000);
          this.user = response.data.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        })
        .then(_ => (this.saving = false));
    }
  },
  created() {
    api.find(this.$route.params.id).then(response => {
      this.loaded = true;
      this.user = response.data.data;
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

It's load data from api very slowly I see firstly empty inputs in view and after some short time I see data, if I open api data from laravel I see data immediately, so my question is How speed up it? Or maby I did something wrong?

Comment: is this also happens in production build? I have similar issue when in dev mode, I guess it's the limitation of the webpack dev server.

Comment: no it's dev mode, I use npm run watch or npm run dev or npm run prod and I use homestead server, how check it in production when I have homestead is it possible? or maybe you know some free or cheap serwer for laravel and vue? I try netifly but it is not working with laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I am using an API with Vue, I usually make most of my API calls before opening the Vue then passing it in like this.

```
<vue-component :user="'{!! $user_data !!}'"></vue-component>
```

But if you have to do it in the Vue component, I am not sure if this will show improvement over your method but I would set it up with the "mounted" like so.

```
export default {
    mounted() {
        api.find(this.$route.params.id).then(response => {
          this.loaded = true;
          this.user = response.data.data;
        });
    }
}
```

Also [heres](https://pusher.com/tutorials/laravel-vue-axios) a good tutorial on Axios and how to use HTTP Requets with Vue.

Hopefully this answered your question, good luck!